# How to get a particular branch from github

Tags: git, github, pyqtgraph

I am trying to get the version of pyqtgraph that has the DateAxisItem change which does not appear to be merged into the main source.

[date-axis-item](https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph/tree/date-axis-item/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems)

What command do I issue to git to get this branch?

I tried

```
git clone https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph -b https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph/tree/date-axis-item/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The branch you are trying to check out is in a different repository (a fork), so you'll want to clone *that* repository and then you can use the `-b` switch to specify the name of the branch, like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph -b date-axis-item
```

Comment: TY both. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>

git clone -b date-axis-item git@github.com:3rdcycle/pyqtgraph.git
```

Or,

```
git clone -b date-axis-item https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph.git
```